# Sonar Duplication is not working as expected?

Tags: sonarqube

Am trying to show someone over here how good I find the sonar 
tool...
then I wrote a small java  project and defined many intentionally smelly methods,
2 of those are exactly the same (copy+paste) ***do1*** and ***do2***

surprisenly, after running the sonnar, there is no duplication error nor warnings...

```
public void do1() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            System.out.println(new Date());
        }
    }
}

public void do2() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i != 0) {
            System.out.println(new Date());
            System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

what is the criteria for a java project to raise a warning on duplicates then?

[image]

Comment: Your two methods are not even duplicates!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your methods are too short to show up as duplicated. [Per the docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions#MetricDefinitions-Duplications),

> There should be at least 10 successive and duplicated statements whatever the number of tokens and lines.

Comment: Thanks... I added some more lines and now is showing the duplicated block! :)

Comment: Can I somehow configure that? I mean who writes methods longer than 10 lines anyhow?!

Comment: @BalázsNémeth check the `sonar.cpd.*` parameters: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters/

Comment: Thanks but "For Java projects, a piece of code is considered duplicated when there is a series of at least 10 statements in a row, regardless of the number of tokens and lines. This threshold cannot be overridden." Doesn't it mean I cannot have less than 10?